# Online - Search not returning video files in results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

I've created a communication site on SharePoint Online with an Asset Library.

A couple of days ago I've uploaded three MP4 videos in that library. After some time I've tried to search these files, but I wasn't able to get the result directly to the MP4 file.

When a video is uploaded in an Asset Library, it creates a folder and then, into that folder, the uploaded video is placed. So, I was only able to get that container folder in search results.

I've also tried and tested with the "Build Your Query" tool in site settings. This is the query I'm using:

```
{searchTerms} FileType=mp4 Path={Site.URL}
```

It returns 0 results.

It is the common behaviour of the search engine? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The query should be

```
{searchTerms} FileType=mp4 Path:{Site.URL}
```

Using `Path={Site.URL}` will not return any result, at least not from my test results.

Just a reminder, you can search for the full filename of the MP4 video (or search `FileType=mp4`) just to confirm if the video file is crawled in this site. Since the crawling process is managed by Microsoft, we can do nothing but wait.

Comment: Hi! I tried the query you suggested but it returns 0 results.

Comment: @Pepozzo Do you get any result if you search the full name for the video file?

Comment: I tried searching "myvideo" and it returns the video as result. I searched "myvideo.mp4" and it return 0 results. How is that possible?

Comment: @Pepozzo ok...I'm out of ideas. Everything works fine at my end so the query is not the problem. It doesn't look like something we can work to fix.

Comment: Is it possibile it could be the Asset Library? I'll try with a document library.

Comment: @Pepozzo Not sure but you can try. I have video files in both location and they are all searchable. You can try "Reindex Document Library" in Site Assets though, might help.

Comment: I've tried with a document library and now I'm able to get the mp4 in search results.

Comment: @Pepozzo Ok good to know. Thanks for sharing.